# Nested queries - undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have written a function and exported it using exports. Inside the function I have 2 nested queries. When I have only 1 query I am able to view the values of result. But, after adding the outer query the value of the result from the outer query is undefined.

Here is the code:
main.js

```
var new1 = function () {
  connection.query("select ID from tbl1", function (error, result, fields) {
    console.log(result) // This is displayed as undefined.
    for (var id in result) {
      connection.query("select name from tbl2 where ID = '" + result[id].ID + "' ", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err

        for (var count in result) {
          console.log(result[count].name)
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
export.new1 = new1;
```

and in the app.js:

```
  var new2 = require('./main');
  new2.new1();
```

Thank you.

Comment: The comment in the code says `result` is `displayed as undefined.` If that's true none of the loops will work.

Comment: Yeah, none of the loops are working.... Is this something related to Asynchronous programming?

Comment: @Yodha no, your async code is correct in this case. are you sure you have a tbl1?

Comment: The query might return an error, you should check for that in your code. Your query might also return no results.

Comment: @Mark_M suggests adding this line above console.log(result) and rerunning the code.

if (error) { throw error }

Comment: @MattPengelly I have added the if(error). There are no errors. Now, I am getting the result as [ ].

Comment: hmm, check to see if the database column is ID or id, the terminal client may have different behaviour for case sensitivity. Just a guess. It might also help others if you included which library youre using to connect to your DB in your js code.

Comment: @MattPengelly Sorry, it worked fine... I was working on wrong server. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to edit and fix your indentation, but then I saw you are missing a closing quote for the string on the second line: `"select ID from tbl1`

Now someone else have edited your code and added a closing quote

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have edited the code but same output.

Comment: Oh, ok. Well, then there is no result from your query.

Comment: Things like this are almost always just copying errors, since a syntax error would prevent the code from running at all, it wouldn't produce unexpected results.